# microsoft-graph-client Get emails

Tags: node.js, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of emails using microsoft-graph-client. I got a refresh_token and configured App + secret. My App have Mail.Read permission

My code:

```
const { Client } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const clientId = process.env.OUTLOOK_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.OUTLOOK_SECRET;
const tenantId = process.env.OUTLOOK_TENANT_ID;
const refreshToken = process.env.OUTLOOK_REFRESH_TOKEN;

async function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
        params.append('client_id', clientId);
        params.append('client_secret', clientSecret);
        params.append('refresh_token', refreshToken);
        params.append('scope', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default');

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: params,
        });
        // console.log(response)

        const data = await response.json();
        return data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

async function getNewEmails(accessToken) {
    try {
        const client = Client.init({
            authProvider: (done) => {
                done(null, accessToken);
            },
        });

        const response = await client.api("/me/messages").top(10).get()

        return response.value;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
        const newEmails = await getNewEmails(accessToken);
        console.log(newEmails);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})();
```

I get an error at the moment of calling the "await client.api("/me/messages").top(10).get()" function

Error:

```
GraphError
    at new GraphError (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\lib\src\GraphError.js:34:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\lib\src\GraphErrorHandler.js:97:30)
    at step (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:193:27)
    at Object.next (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:174:57)
    at D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:167:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:163:16)
    at GraphErrorHandler.getError (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\lib\src\GraphErrorHandler.js:87:24)
    at GraphRequest.<anonymous> (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\lib\src\GraphRequest.js:315:84)
    at step (D:\Tools\Bots\bot\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:193:27) {
  statusCode: 401,
  code: null,
  requestId: null,
  date: 2023-11-14T18:18:41.708Z,
  body: ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
}
```

I checked access_token from "getAccessToken()" it does not come "undefined", I get everything right ( I think). So my main problem is with getting the emails. I understand that 401 means "Not authorized", but I don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using the client credentials flow then

> "/me/messages"

isn't a valid endpoint as the service principal doesn't have a Mailbox. You need to use the users endpoint of a users mailbox you want to access eg

```
"/user/mailbox@blah.com/messages"
```

The service principal will then impersonate that user, you can lock down the users your app can access using policies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access which is a good idea if you only need access to subset of mailboxes.